# Java switch case statement - multiple entries for a case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need to have the same statement for 2 or 3 conditions.
How can I do this ?
ex:

```
switch(var)
    case 0:
        statement1
    break;
    case 1: 
        statement1
    break
```

I need to say sth like

```
case 1,0:
   statement1
```

is this feasible ?

Comment: What about `case 0 : case 1 : statement1; break;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this

```
switch(in){
  case 0:
  case 1:
   //statement1 ; // now statement1 valid for both case 0 and 1
  break;
  case 2:
   //statement2
  break;

}
```

[IdeOne](http://ideone.com/sxCMOU) example.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
switch(var)
    case 0:
    case 1: 
        statement1
    break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This is why switch has [fall through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) behaviour in Java  -

```
switch(var)
  case 0: // no break, so it falls through
  case 1: // case 0 or 1
    statement1();
    break;
  default: // not 0 or 1
    // something else.
}
```

Or you can use an `if` with an `||` like so

```
if (var == 0 || var == 1) {
  statement1();
} else { // not 0 or 1
  // something else.
}
```